# OneSignal not accepting player id 'invalid_player_ids' when sending notification via REST API

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2, onesignal

I'm using OneSignal for mobile push notification, but some devices' ids got in invalid_player_ids when sending the notification from my REST API.

It have happened with different devices. Both android and ios.

Current i'm using an android device. And my scenarios is:
I install my app on android. The id is generated and sent to my backend application. My application try to send notification to the generated id, it fail with error invalid_player_ids and my device id.

How i can manage to solve the id to check if its valid or not?

Thanks

Comment: Any leads since October?Have you sorted it out?

Comment: @AndyStrife i discover it happens when a mobile no longer has my app or notifications subscribtion on, then this happen

Comment: I'm getting the same error too , how can I clear them up ?

Comment: I'm getting the same error as well, some solution?

Comment: any clue on it?

Answer (score -1):

Just clear your device's cache and resubscribe

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33915145)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).